# How to get type of matplotlib plot (scatter vs. line vs. contour etc...)?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, mpld3

I am trying to abstract some plugins in mpld3, and depending on which type of plot is contained in my figure (ie scatter vs. line vs. contour), I want to use a different plugin.  I'm having trouble figuring out the canonical way to distinguish the category of a matplotlib axes.  Right now, I'm inspecting the return of the various calls:

For a scatter plot:

```
type(plt.scatter(range(10), range(10)))
**matplotlib.collections.PathCollection**
```

For a line plot:

```
x = plt.plot([1,2,3])
print x
**[<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0xcd646ec>]**
```

For an image plot:

```
type(ax.imshow(np.random.randn(50,50)))
**matplotlib.image.AxesImage**
```

Etc...

Is there a more canonical way to access the axes type from the axes itself?  Something like:

```
if ax.plottype == 'scatter':
    ....
elif ax.plottype == 'contour':
    ....
```

I guess since I can stack multiple artists onto a plot, maybe this is just not a sensible question?

Comment: This seems a bit ill-posed as there isn't a one-to-one mapping between Axes and plot. In other words, I could draw both a contour plot and a scatterplot on the same axes.

Comment: Ya, that's true.  I will delete the question in a day or so., just want to see if it sparks some information that might help me.

Comment: Not sure how big a project you are up for, but you could consider replacing/extending the plot types in `matplotlib`, so that they stored the information you need in the axes object.